# I can't get my thumbnails to preview on fancybox-3

Tags: php, html, jquery, fancybox

```
<?php 
// Include database configuration file  
// Retrieve images from the database 
$query = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY uploaded_date DESC"); 
    if(!$query) {
        trigger_error("Invalid query: " . $DB->error);
    }
if($query->num_rows > 0){ 
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $imageURL = '../phpgallery/'.$row["path"]; 
?>
    <a href="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" data-fancybox="gallery" data-caption="<?php echo $row["title"]; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $imageURL; ?>" alt="" width="300"/>
</a>
<?php } 
} ?>
```

This is where images are fetched. I haven't got smaller thumbnail images and I would prefer not to.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
            // Options will go here
            arrows: true,
            loop: true,
            wheel: "auto",
            protect: true,
            buttons : [ 
                'zoom',
                'fullScreen',
                'close'
            ]
        });
```

Some images are stretched out filling the width of the screen.[image: image of my website]

There are two stretched images on the site, under 2gb. The lower one is overlapping the image below it.

(side now, loop and protect don't work)

Comment: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: @Dharman I don't think there is an issue with MySQL, but its with fancybox.